# to print some data instead of data which are fetched from database

Tags: php, mysql

I make one email function in that function i set the code of email template and also set the value which are i fetched from database.i upload one image in which the status field is 3 now i want to print confirmed instead of 3 in my email template.Here in the order array i get all the data.What i do to print Confirmed
instead of 3.

```
public function setworkerTemplate($RESPONSE,$name)
    {
        $temp=$RESPONSE['temp'];
        $order=$RESPONSE['order'];
        $cust=$RESPONSE['cust'];
        $workers=$RESPONSE['workers'];
          echo "<pre>";
        print_r($order); 




            $logo=JURI::root()."images/logo-1.png";
                    $html ='<html>';
        $html.='<body>';
            $html.='<div style="width:100%;   background-color:#f6f6f6; border-top:#337ab7 5px solid; border-bottom:#337ab7 5px solid;">';
                $html.='<div style=" margin-left:15%;  margin-right:15%; ">';
                    $html.='<div style=" margin-top:5%;">';
                        $html.='<center><img src="'.$logo.'" style="width:200px; height:100px;"></center>';
                    $html.='</div>';
                    $html.='<div style=" margin-top:1%; color: #666; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 16px;">';
                        $html.='<b>Dear ,'.$workers['firstname'].'</b><br>';
                        $html.='<br>';                      
                        $html.='<b>Please find details about your schedule today for <a href="#">steamatichv.com</a> below.</b><br>';
                        $html.='<br>';
                        $html.='<table style="width:100%;" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5"  bgcolor="#FFFFFF" bordercolor="#cccccc ">';
                            $html.='<tr  style=" box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #888888;;">';
                                $html.='<td  style="padding-left: 5px;"><b>Order Number</b></td>';
                                $html.='<td style="padding-left: 5px;"><b>Schedule Date</b></td>';
                                $html.='<td style="padding-left: 5px;"><b>Schedule Time</b></td>';
                                $html.='<td style="padding-left: 5px;"><b>Status</b></td>';
                            $html.='</tr>';
                            $html.='<tr>';
                                $html.='<td>'.$order['Order_number'].'</td>';
                                $html.='<td>'.$order['schedule_date'].'</td>';
                                $html.='<td>'.$order['schedule_timeslot'].'</td>';
                                **[$html.='<td>'.$order\['published'\].'</td>';][1]**
                            $html.='</tr>';
                        $html.='</table><br>'; 
$html.='<div style=" margin-top:1%; color: #666; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 16px;">';
                        $html.='<p>Regards,<br>Steamatic HV Team</p>';      
                    $html.='</div>';
                $html.='</div>';  
            $html.='</div>';
        $html.='</body>';
    $html.='</html>';
     return $html; 

    }
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense `$s1='';
        if($s1->published == 3) { echo "Confirmed"; }`

Comment: i just tried to print confirmed instead of 3 any idea about that?

Comment: your `if($s1->published == 3)` wont ever fall true..coz you wrote `$s1=''` line above

Comment: which variable contain `3`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ternary operator](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators).

```
$html.='<td>'.($order['published'] == 3 ? 'Confirmed' : 'Unconfirmed').'</td>';
```

If you have more than one case:

```
$html .= '<td>';

if($order['published'] == 1)
  $html .= 'Pending';
else if($order['published'] == 2)
  $html .= 'Cancelled';
else if($order['published'] == 3)
  $html .= 'Confirmed';
else
  $html .= 'Unknown';

$html .= '</td>';
```

Comment: Nice catch . Add semicolon at the end of line .

Comment: This is working but i want to use 3 status in my table if status=1->pending,status=2->cancelled,status=3->confirmed .?

Comment: simple use `else if`